# ArgumentMatchers not working after PowerMockito version update

Tags: mockito, powermock, jacoco, powermockito

I have an partial Mock that is not working anymore after an update from PowerMock 1.4.8 to 1.7.0RC4 to solve a sonar/jacoco incompatibility that was lowing the code coverage. After that, all the mocks that use matchers as parameters are not being called. The code looks like:

```
Calculator calc = mock(Calculator.class);
when(calc.getA()).thenReturn(new BigDecimal("1"));
when(calc.getB()).thenReturn(new BigDecimal("2"));
when(calc.calculate(any(Date.class), anyInt(), any(MyObject.class))).thenCallRealMethod();
```

The last mock method is never call when passing real parameters. I notice that this only happens due the use of Matchers of non-primitive types such as MyObject. Can anyone help me with this issue?

My pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0RC4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0RC4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0RC4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

PS: I am already using ArgumentMatchers instead of Matchers api.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you really *need* the "power" parts of PowerMock(ito) - did you try to go with plain Mockito instead?

Comment: @GhostCat yeah. All the functions used are from org.mockito package despite i had said it was after the PowerMockito update i am using in this test class the mockito-core-2.7.5.jar dependence of powermock-core

Comment: Could you check it with release version (I mean 1.7.0). If it still reproduce then please raise an issue on Github. I'll investigate.